# Calculate x z movement on plane with camera rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, hammer.js

I move an Object 3D with HammerJS in an AR space.

It works fine as long as I don't move my phone (which is the camera)...

```
const newTranslation = new THREE.Vector3(this._initTranslation.x + e.deltaX, this._initTranslation.y, this._initTranslation.z + e.deltaY);
```

the init... are the original ones of the Object3D

When I move around the movement still is on the x z axes i began with. (I move my finger up on the phone (to move the Object backwards(on the z-axis)) instead it moves from left to right)

I know that I have to take the camera rotation into the count, to translate from camera to world but have no clue how to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it my self. Here is my solution in case someone needs it:

I now rotate the point with my camera rotation angle:

```
const movePoint = new THREE.Vector2(e.deltaX, e.deltaY);
movePoint.rotateAround(new THREE.Vector2(0, 0), this.getCameraAngle());

const newTranslation = new THREE.Vector3(this._initTranslation.x + movePoint.x, 
this._initTranslation.y, this._initTranslation.z + movePoint.y);
```

And for the camera angle:

```
public getCameraAngle (): number {
  const cameraDir = new THREE.Vector3();
  this._arCamera.getWorldDirection(cameraDir);
  cameraDir.setY(0);
  cameraDir.normalize();

  return Math.atan2(cameraDir.z, cameraDir.x) - Math.atan2(-1, 0);
}
```